# Unable to insert data in table in Postgres sql commands

Tags: postgresql

This is my query

```
INSERT INTO EForms_M_FormTypeMaster (FormTypeId,FormTypeCode,FormTypeName) 
VALUES ('12','FM','Form');
```

Getting this error

> Error Message relation "eforms_m_modulemaster" does not exist

Please help to solve the issue

Comment: Question was quiet different which is related to postgres and I am asking in my way and previous post was related to PHP and my post related to nodejs

Answer (score 2):

Where is the table? If it is in public then you must aware about case insensitive. That means if your table realname is  `EForms_M_FormTypeMaster` you must put it between `"`

```
INSERT INTO "EForms_M_FormTypeMaster" ("FormTypeId","FormTypeCode","FormTypeName")
    VALUES ('12','FM','Form');
```

Comment: After mentioning 
INSERT INTO "EForms_M_FormTypeMaster" (FormTypeId,FormTypeCode,FormTypeName)
    VALUES ('12','FM','Form');

I got this error

Error Message column "formtypeid" of relation "EForms_M_FormTypeMaster" does not exist

Comment: @Sprasanth: When you use case-sensitive column names, you must protect them with double quotes like the table name. I've updated the post.

Comment: I got it, Thank you